# compare two images and output their histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two *b&w images* that I would like to compare using a histogram.

I am using the following code to display a histogram of a single image:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = plt.imread('222.jpg', 0)
histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
plt.plot(histr)
plt.show()
```

I get the output histogram:

[image]

Could you tell me please, how do I make it so that *two histograms* of two *b&w images* are displayed on the output graph, for example, the first image is displayed with a *red line*, and the second image with a *blue line*, well, or any other *histogram format*.
Also, please tell me how I can get the data of my *b&w images* so that I can build a histogram in *excel*, for example.
Thank you very much!

Comment: if you add a second `plt.plot(histr2)` before `plt.show()` this should work automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to mention the plots of both the b&w images and then display it
2. Choose colors using `color` flag within `plot()`

**Code:**

```
img1 = plt.imread('image_1.jpg', 0)
img2 = plt.imread('image_2.jpg', 0)

# histogram of both images
hist1 = cv2.calcHist([img1],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
hist2 = cv2.calcHist([img2],[0],None,[256],[0,256])

# plot both the histograms and mention colors of your choice
plt.plot(hist1,color='red')
plt.plot(hist2, color='green')

plt.show()
```

[image]

To answer your second question, store the values in `hist1` and `hist2` as two separate columns in a dataframe. Save the dataframe as an excel or CSV file. You can later open the file, select the columns and plot.